# Unrelated use of [jupyter-notebook] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I see a lot of questions tagged [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook) from people who are *using* Jupyter Notebook e.g. as their primary Python development environment, but where the question really has nothing to do with the fact that they happen to be using it.

Similar problem goes for other IDEs like [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code), though for now I'm focusing primarily on Jupyter.

It's true that it's often difficult, especially for beginners, to determine whether their problem has to do with the programming language/libraries they're using, or whether it has something to do with the development environment (often they are not even sure of the difference).

Does it make sense then, when reviewing a question, if I can make a clear determination about this to remove the development environment tags that are unrelated to the question?

Relatedly, would it make sense to add a note about this to the [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook) tag wiki?  In particular I'd like to add a hint about how to determine whether the problem really has to do with Jupyter Notebook?  E.g., can the problem be reproduced in the standard Python REPL (or same for other languages if they're not using the Python kernel)?

Comment: *"Does it make sense [...] to remove the development environment tags that are unrelated to the question?"* - yes, of course. I do that alot when users tag with `pycharm` just because they use it but the question has absolutely nothing to do with Pycharm. If you want to go the extra mile, watch the tag or add it to a custom filter and edit any non-related uses

Comment: It's a common problem. People tag the IDE they are using *not* the language, framework or underlying service; such as [[tag:vs-code]] for a problem they are facing in [[tag:python]] but writing in said IDE, or [[tag:ssms]] for questions about [[tag:sql-server]]/[[tag:tsql]]. Just edit out the tag and, if needed, add the relevant tags in. If you really want to, leave a comment educating the user why they tagged incorrectly.